# match algorithm javascript without regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

I need an algorithm for solving this problem **withou** using **regEx**

"Does a string follow a 123-456-7890 pattern like a phone number?
This problem asks you to create a function that can accept a string and then
determine if that string follows the pattern presented. For example, if you pass
the string “123-45-67”, this would not match the pattern. But, if you passed the
string “407-695-0100”, this would match the pattern. The only value returned
from the function should be a Boolean; that is, true if the string matches the
pattern or false if it does not"

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far?

Comment: We won't do your homework for you. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: It seems like you want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: Easy, check out `split()`

Comment: Mike W - I said i need an algorithm not a code because i had no idea where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want an algorithm:

```
function matchTele(txt, i){
    i = i || 0;
    if(txt.length != 12) return false;
    if(i == txt.length) return true;
    if(i == 3 || i == 7){
        return txt[i] == "-" ? matchTele(txt, ++i) : false;
    }
    return isNaN(parseInt(txt[i], 10)) ? false : matchTele(txt, ++i);
}

matchTele("000-000-0000")  //true
matchTele("aaa-aaa-aaaa")  //false - not a valid digit
matchTele("000-00-0000")   //false - length not match
```

Comment: Can you please comment second 6th and 8th line ?

Comment: @GheorgheCojocaru - For the 8th line, it is checking if the current character is a digit for not. If it is, then checking check the next character if it is a digit or not. This is a recursive function, however, you can always do it with the same result using loops, but I like it this way. ;) I will leave the rest for you to figure out how it works.